# How to manage multisite themes from master Drupal installation

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I have Drupal 8 multisite to benefit from a single codebase. **Also they share the same database**. How can I change themes of all the other sites from my main domain/site?

Parent and child domain :

```
- mainsite.com
-- childsite1.com
-- childsite2.com
-- childsite3.com
```

Comment: Manage themes **independently** from your main site?

Answer (score 1):

The [README.txt file in Drupal's /themes directory](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/themes/README.txt) states:

> …the sites/your_site_name/themes directory
>   pattern may be used to restrict themes to a specific site instance.

For instance, you might have:

```
- sites/all/themes/m1
- sites/childsite1.com/themes/c1
- sites/childsite2.com/themes/c2
- sites/childsite3.com/themes/c3
```

Comment: Not bad, but OP uses a shared database...